# Xib to Storyboard issue in copying

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, uistoryboard, xib

I recently migrated from `Xibs` to `Storyboard` in Xcode 6. To do this, I created a new controller in storyboard, deleted the view in storyboard, selected and copied the whole view hierarchy in controller's xib and pasted it to storyboard.

I had to manually **remap outlets** in storyboard and it works.

The problem is I can not see any of the `views` in the `storyboard`, and so can not add any new subviews. All I see is the name of the controller and thats it (see image).

How do I get around with it ?[image]